# Angularjs ng-style firing too soon

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I try to calculate the height of a DOM element to position another element.

Here is the differents parts of code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div>
        <span class="line1">{{ getLine1() }}</span>
        <span class="line2">{{ getLine2() }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab_list" ng-style="{ 'top': getHeaderHeight() + 'px' }">   
    content
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.getHeaderHeight = function() {
    var header = document.getElementsByClassName("header");
    if(header[0])
    {
        if(header[0].offsetHeight)
        {
            return header[0].offsetHeight+5;                
        }           
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Each time the height return is 5.
But, if I do manualy it return the correct value 75.

I suppose it return a bad value because ng-style is called before "getLine1" and "getLine2".

Is there a way to trigger ng-style at last or another way to achieve this ?

Comment: Probably just wrap it in a `$timeout`

Comment: Don't do DOM manipulation from controllers, wrap it inside a directive and do access DOM from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First thing-**

If you are doing DOM manipulations or any calculations that would affect your DOM/HTML directly, write it inside a directive like Pankaj said.

A directive, with the way it is defined, is always attached to a DOM node. So when you define a directive, it "expands" or replaces the dom node to which it is attached.

Dom Manipulations should not exist in controllers, services or anywhere else but in directives.

**Secondly-**

Not sure of $timeout, it might be an overhead to your load time.

A good reference - [Best Practice DOM Manipulation in Angular JS](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/)

Comment: Hi, I'am new to angularjs. Didn't know how worked the directives. But after your advice and some documentation, it works. Thanks a lot.